# Getting data from remote sql table on iphone

Tags: iphone, sql, ios

I am a beginner at both iPhone programming and SQL, yet I have basic knowledge of them.

I am planning to do an application that would plot a graph from data taken from a database of the server of my company. I know how to plot, I know how to extract data from an sql table, but what I don't know is how to access the server.

So do I have to go through some kind of oracle-like application ?

This may seem like a very stupid question because it might not even be possible but any answer will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for all the fast answers! I will look into it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through a web service for example a PHP page that returns JSON (or XML, but JSON is easier to parse).

I can highly recommend [this](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) tutorial

Once you have your web service, you can use [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to download the data and use [a JSON framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) to parse it. Or, if you're using XML you can use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

See [this apple code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for more info on downloading using NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for this will be, using APIs at server end that handle the client request and perform database interaction, so transfer of data among device and server, take place through XMLs that will be secure as well as fast.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to contact a server (I can't imagine what would happen without that!). What you are looking for is `NSURLConnection`. Have a look at [the example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) provided by Apple.